# How do you check for whether a device is in a wifi deadzone?

Tags: wifi

How do you check whether your device is in a wifi deadzone? Specifically, I have a 2007 Macbook.

Environments:

- At home
- At public places with wifi
- Hotel wifi setups

Comment: Could you give more information on your actual wireless environment? For example: what is the source of your Wi-Fi network? Did you try iStumbler?

Comment: I'd like a general solution to try for in hotels, public places with wifi or at home or elsewhere

Comment: Ideally a free solution or a trial one to verify that it actually works at least in the home setting where I know where the deadspots are

Comment: In Network Preferences, make sure "Show wifi icon in menubar" is checked. Then click on the wifi icon, and you'll see the wifi networks the computer "sees." If you see one or more networks, the computer's network hardware is working. If you see none, then either the computer's network hardware is defective or you're in a wifi dead zone. If you option-click on the wifi icon, you'll see specific information about the wifi network that the computer's connected to, which will allow you to assess the quality of the wifi signal.

Comment: Can you add some details on what you consider to be a "wifi deadzone" and why simply opening the WiFi menu on your Mac is not enough?

Comment: Is it: deadzone = area covered by a Wi-Fi access point (in term of distance to the access point d < 25 m) and where the connection will fail for many reasons (interferences, obstacles, reflecting surfaces…)?